# Converting NAs to 0 and non-NA's to 1s in R

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I am having trouble converting a table of NAs and different values to 0 for NAs and 1s for the all the values.

Table looks like this:

```
x    y    z
NA   8    NA
2    NA   NA
9    9    8
...
```

I was able to convert the NAs to 0 using:

```
data[is.na(data)] <- 0
```

But I couldn't manage to convert the other values for all the columns at once.

Comment: `replace(replace(tbl, !is.na(tbl), 1), is.na(tbl), 0)`

Comment: `ifelse(is.na(data), 0, 1)` ?

Comment: `data[] = lapply(data, function(x) as.numeric(!is.na(x)))`

Comment: Similar to @Gregor: `(!is.na(tbl)) * 1`

Comment: @d.b in this case  `1 * !is.na(tbl)` converts to numeric by `!is.na(tbl) * 1` doesn't. I'm not sure why, haven't noticed that difference before...

Comment: @Gregor - The negation out front is applied to the entire expression. `is.na(tbl) * 1` is done first, then the negation.  So you are essentially converting to logical, then numeric, then back to logical.

Comment: `df[] <- as.integer(!is.na(df))` would work too.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with a simple `ifelse` (one-liner):

```
data <- data.frame(ifelse(is.na(data),0,1))
```

Or even easier:

```
+!is.na(data)
```

Both will give you:

```
##   x y z
## 1 0 1 0
## 2 1 0 0
## 3 1 1 1
```

***Data:***

```
data <- structure(list(x = c(NA, 2L, 9L), y = c(8L, NA, 9L), z = c(NA,               
     NA, 8L)), .Names = c("x", "y", "z"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Note that `+(!is.na(data))` returns a matrix

Comment: @RichScriven Yeah, but we don't actually know if the OP has a matrix, data.table, dataframe or what as s/he has not posted the structure.

Answer (score 4):

Following the same approach as you mentioned in your example:

```
# example data
df = data.frame(x = c(5,4,NA),
                y = c(NA,3,9))

df

#    x  y
# 1  5 NA
# 2  4  3
# 3 NA  9

df[!is.na(df)] = 1
df[is.na(df)] = 0

#   x y
# 1 1 0
# 2 1 1
# 3 0 1
```

First replace all non NA values with 1 and then (the remaining) NAs with 0.
If you replace NAs first, then all your values will be non NA and you'll end up with a dataframe full of 1s.

Answer (score 2):

```
data <- matrix(data = c(1:9),nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
data[3,3] <- NA

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6   NA

data[data > 0] <- 1
data[is.na(data)] <- 0

      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    0
```

Comment: AntoniosK's order (replace non-NA values first) is a little more general - if there is a possibility of 0s or negatives that should become 1s, changing NA to 0 first with miss them.